# Rails - Make ajax request from javascript event and load partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

what's up?

I'm using rails 3.2.3 with ruby 1.9.2p290.

I have a model Purchase which has many purchase_payments:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchase_payments, :class_name => 'PurchasePayment', :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :purchase_payments

  def Purchase.build_payments(count)
    #Creat #count payments with some logic for each of them
  end
end
```

In my form, I have number_field:

```
<td>
  <%= f.number_field :payments_count, :min => 0 %>
</td>
```

Now, I'd like to have the purchase_payment fields appear based on the number of payments. For that, I have a specific div:

```
<div id="purchase_payments_space"> </div>
```

Every resource I've found so far, talks about ajax generated by helper tags, like link_to ... , :remote => true, but using this tags, the user would have to click on the link to have the remote function called. In other part of my app, I use jquery ajax request and I'm trying to use like this for sending the request to my controller:

```
function load_payments() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/purchases/build_payments/" + document.getElementById("purchase_payments_count").value,
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#purchase_payments_count").change(load_payments);
}
```

In my controller, I have the respond_to :js right after my class declaration and the following method:

```
def build_payments
  pc = params[:payments_count].to_i
  @purchase = Purchase.new

  @purchase_payments = Purchase.build_payments pc

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

This way I have my app/views/purchases/buid_payments.js.erb run ok.
The thing is, I'm building a collection of payments that should be included in my form, and doing things the way I'm currently doing doesn't look like rails would do this. This way I will have to write much code in the js.erb file and still I can't figure out how I'll make the create method build the complete purchase from the params (I don't know how to build the form from the javascript).

I looked at several different ways but none have given an integrated solution for making an ajax request from a javascript event and have the view create the nested fields for my nested attributes (its a collection of purchase_payment I must remember).

I saw http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2 but those build on top of helper methods like link_to and link_to_function.

Can anyone point me how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "purchases/build_payments",
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#purchase_payments_count').val(),
    dataType: 'html',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': '<%= form_authenticity_token.to_s %>'
    }
});
```

then

```
def build_payments
  pc = params[:payments_count].to_i
  @purchase = Purchase.new

  @purchase_payments = Purchase.build_payments pc

  respond_to do |f|
    f.js {}
  end
end
```

which will run buid_payments.js.erb which can populate\recreate your table

If can't see it I can't help you.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this will change the response from the server.